# How to mock module dependencies in module spec file?

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have a module that imports Kendo's IntlModule and the spec file with Jest is throwing an error.

a.module.ts

```
import { IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
import '@progress/kendo-angular-intl/locales/en-GB/all';

@NgModule({
    import: [ IntlModule ]
})
export class AModule { }
```

a.module.spec.ts

This is the default module spec which I currently have:

```
import { AModule } from './a.module';

describe('AModule', () => {
  let aModule: AModule;

  beforeEach(() => {
    aModule = new AModule();
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(aModule).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I get following error:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { setData } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

      24 |       }
    > 26 |     }),
         | ^
      27 |     IntlModule
      28 |   ],
      29 |   exports: [
```

How could I mock the IntlModule to make the test pass?

Comment: Not sure this is a testing error there ...

Comment: Look into the TestBed class

Comment: There is no TestBed, this spec is what I get by generating the module via the CLI

Comment: Btw I wrote this question also about if these tests make sense: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132542/does-it-make-sense-to-have-spec-file-for-angular-modules